# label not aligning with select box

Tags: html, css, angular

My label is not aligning with my select box. Instead, it is sitting below the previous div, which is in the middle of the page.

The select box sits to the far left. The `for` and `name` values match, so I don't understand why they are separated.

I am using `style="display:inline;"` on the previous div and `style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top"` on the div following.

Even if I replace `label` with `span` it still sits under the previous div in the centre of the page. Any ideas?

This is the whole problem div.

```
  <div class="form-group">
  <div class="dropdown" dropdown>
  <label class="label-text" for="unit" >Cm/Inch</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="unit" style="width:150px;" 
(ngModelChange)="onUnitChange($event)"
          [(ngModel)]="job_entry.units" name="unit">
    <option disabled hidden [value]="undefined">select unit </option>
    <option  value="cm">centimeters</option>
    <option  value="inch">inches</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show your CSS? It's probably `dropdown` class that causes the problem.

Comment: label-tex has `.label-text {
  font-family: "Times new roman", times, monospace;
  font-size: 20px;
}` but that is all. Nothing works to align them.

Comment: And the other classes? As I said, I think that `dropdown` class is what causing the problem. Try to get rid of it just for the sake of testing and see if it helps.

Comment: got rid of it, no change. I use float:left on it, the whole select box moves to the labels right, opposite of what I want.

Comment: I'm assuming that you are using bootstrap. Try wrapping `label` and `select` in a div with `form-inline` class